Why the output of my project that uses docker build to publish a custom image of Debian, is different when ran locally vs Github actions?
I have a small project that takes the latest minimal snapshot of Debian from debian.org and after applying a sequence of dockerfile & shell scripts, outputs a gzip image. This gzip can directly be written on a disk using rufus or similar tool and it will be ready to boot on any compatible hardware.
But, I am facing a weird issue. When ran locally in Git Bash, the output image works fine, but when ran on Github using actions, the final image fails to boot up. It gives following error on boot:
Boot_error_GitHub_Actions_Image
Please help me understand what could be different in local GitBash vs GitHub Actions project execution.
Here is my build flow on GitHub:
`linux-os.yml
    -> build.sh (*uses a dockerfile & calls methods from buildhelper.sh*)
        -> buildhelper.sh (*It has all the methods like docker build*)
            -> squash-me.sh (*It has methods to configure the root partition of OS*)
`

The above complete flow runs on GitHub actions. However, on local Git bash, I directly call build.sh. The kind of error that is coming on boot screen, it seems like something weird is happening while calling squash-me.sh on GitHub actions, because of that, the root partition fails to load during boot.

Doesn’t look like you’re using Ubuntu - maybe try here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Ask Ubuntu is about support for Ubuntu and its official flavors. Your question is related to another distribution than Ubuntu plus part of the problem seems to be GitHub, so your question is not really related to any Linux distribution. Please consider asking your question in a more appropriate support forum than Ask Ubuntu.
